# How to see a tensor object output of keras?

Tags: keras, tensor

As we know:
Keras.layers.Embedding turns positive integers (indexes) into dense vectors of fixed size. e.g. [[4], [20]] -> [[0.25, 0.1], [0.6, -0.2]]

I want to know how can I see or print the dense vector output.
Or
how to see a tensor object's output?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look here : https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer

In a few words :
Create a new model from your trained model with the output layer in which you are interested, then use the methode predict.

```
layer_name = 'my_layer'
intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model.input,
                             outputs=model.get_layer(layer_name).output)
intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(data)
```